# Base class as argument in derived class constructor in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having trouble with constructors in derived classes. Lets say I have the simple code below here with one base class Base and two classes whom inherits from Base, Derived1 and Derived2.

I want Derived2 to hold a pointer to Base, which could point either to Base or Derived1. I cannot manage to write the constructor for this tho. If I pass in a Derived1 object I get a empty Base once inside the constructor.

```
Class Base
{
public:
      Base(int a): m_a(a)
      {
      }

protected:
         int m_a;
};


//First derived class of base
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
        Derived1(double c): m_c(c)
        {
        }

private:
        double m_c;
};


//Second derived class of Base
class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
        Derived2(Base b, int k): m_b(&b), m_k(k)
        {
        }

private:
        int m_k;
        Base* m_b;
};


int main()
{
    Base b(2);
    Derived1 d1(3.0);


    Derived2 d2(d1, 3);
    Derived2 d3(b, 4);
}
```

Comment: Your looking for composition rather than inheritance there.

Comment: ... and you should know that `Derived2` instance will end up with a completely illegitimate `m_b` value after construction. You're saving the address of a local variable (the copy `Base b`, which you likely did not intend to be [**sliced**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), but none-the-less is.)

Comment: Add `virtual ~Base() {}` to the base class and use RTTI (dynamic_cast) as needed. Maybe you get rid of all derived member data and have a union in base (with an additional member describing the type (int, double, ...))

Comment: you are passing a copy, pass base as a pointer or reference: Derived2(Base &b, int k): m_b(b), m_k(k)

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to accept a `Base*` in your constructor, rather than an actual `Base` instance:

```
Derived2(Base* b, int k) : m_b(b), m_k(k)
{
}
```

Then you can pass the address-of the instance that you want your `Derived2` instance to point to:

```
Derived2 d2(&d1, 3);
Derived2 d3(&b, 4);
```

Note that you should give them thought to the ownership of the `Base` object being pointed to in the `Derived2` instances. Additionally, if the `Derived2` object persists after the passed `Base` object has been deleted, accessing `m_b` will result in undefined behavior. If you can use C++11, consider passing and storing `std::shared_ptr<Base>` instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want `Derived2` to hold a pointer to another `Base` object.

**First issue:**  your constructor uses a value argument for the base object:

```
    Derived2(Base b, int k): m_b(&b), m_k(k)
```

This means that when it gets called, a temporary copy of the parameter passed for b is made, and you will store the address of this temporary object.  Of course, once you leave the statement calling the constructor, this address gets invalid.  Segfault guaranteed sooner or later !

***Solution:***  pass argument by reference (rest of code unchanged):

```
    Derived2(Base& b, int k): m_b(&b), m_k(k)
```

**Second issue:**  Your code doesn't compile, because `Base` doesn't have  default constructor and the constructor for `Derived1` and `Derived2` do not provide for a valid `Base` in their initialisation list.

***Solution 1:*** Either provide an explicit base intialisation in ALL  derived constructors.  For example :

```
    Derived2(Base& b, int k) : m_b(&b), m_k(k), Base(k)  // is k the right value ? 
    { ... }
```

***Solution 2:*** Or consider using a default value for the parameter of `Base` constructor:

```
    Base(int a=0): m_a(a)  // default parameter is 0 
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems here. Let's ignore the design problems with Derived2 for now (naked pointers are evil).

Focussing on `Derived1`...

Derived1 is derived from Base, which means it *is a* Base. Base has only a 1-argument constructor (and therefore no default constructor)

Derived1 has a 1-argument constructor also, but this argument is initialising Derived1's data (`m_c`).

Since Derived *is a* Base, the Base part of it must be constructed at construction time. Since you must construct Base, and base has only a 1-argument constructor, you must specifically mention this in the constructor of Derived1.

Like this:

```
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1(double c, int some_value_for_base)
    : Base(some_value_for_base)
    , m_c(c)
    {
    }

...
};
```